# how it is possible to acess private variables within copy assignment operator?

Tags: c++

I have class called "A" which has a private variable called "var"(with public getters and setter)

I can write copy assignment operator as following

```
A& operator = (const A& rhs)
{
    cout<<"copy assignment operator"<<endl;
    setVal(rhs.var);//Q - how rhs acess directly "a"
}
```

When i compile and run , it run without any problem.

Now my problem is how can i access "var" private variable in Class A object rhs , without any problem?

Comment: How is your problem a problem?

Comment: As far as i know we cannot access private variables using a instance directly.In this case class is A.Instance of Class A is "rhs" . Then how is it possible to get "var" using rhs.var statement(according to encapsulation).Please Correct me if my concepts are wrong

Comment: "When i compile and run , it run without any problem."....so there IS no problem.

Comment: @jpo38: If the compiler is compiling something which you don't think should compile, then that is definitely a problem. The problem may be that there is a bug in the compiler, or it may be that the OP's understanding of this area of the language is incorrect. Either way, it is a problem that should be corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'private' in C++ means 'private to this class' not 'private to this instance'. Private members can be accessed by any function in the class, including static functions, and also in functions declared as 'friends' of the class.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Now my problem is how can i access "var" private variable in Class A object rhs , without any problem?"*

Code that is within member functions, can access any members (`private` or not) of other class instances as well.